# InstallShield LE Files In Use

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I created an installer for a WPF app using InstallShield LE in VS 2013. The installer usually works fine, but one of my clients gets a dialog that says a bunch of completely non-related applications are going to be updated by the installer, including Excel, Outlook, Visual Studio, etc...

This obviously looks suspicious and the client won't complete the installation.

Any ideas on what could cause this? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield routinely complains about files if you have folders even just open, close the folders and it stops barking.